Do we need the 'psychology' or other catch-all tag?
The 'psychology' tag gets recreated on the site from time to time. Here is a previous discussion on the topic from 2012. Since it has been 3 years, I thought it a good idea to rehash. 
I think it is a useless tag, since the majority of questions are already about psychology, and we have more informative [subtype of]-psychology tags already in place.
I also fear that having such vague tags encourages bad posting, since people don't take the time to figure out which tags are best to use; i.e. where their question actually fits. However, it seems that when a 'psychology' tag is unavailable, people just tag things they don't know how to tag as 'cognitive-psychology', making it our general dump tag. So maybe we should consider creating a 'general-psychology' tag? Maybe it will clean up the 'cognitive-psychology' tag, or maybe it will increase the rate of poorly tagged questions.
So the two questions for the community:

Should we eliminate (by re-tagging) and ban the 'psychology' tag?
Should we have a 'general-psychology' tag for people that don't know how to tag their psych questions?


I agree it is a useless tag, and the cognitive-psychology tag gets abused because it is equally useless, IMO. I mean, the site is called Cognitive Sciences; non-cognitivists don't exactly come around here much.

@ChristianHummeluhr - I am around pretty often, not being a cognitivist :)

@AliceD Er, what are you, then? All your answers seem to be informed by cognitive assumptions, to my eye. (Not to offend, just genuinely curious how you see yourself theoretically if not as a cognitivist.)
Good answer though, I'm changing my position to that.

I agree. Clean up guys.

I must say that, not being a 'cognitivist' (is that an existing term?) I have had great difficulty interpreting this site's name and what Cognitive Sciences SE factually accepts as on-topic questions. Given that Psychology is not in this SE's title, it may be not out-of-the-ordinary that folks wish to tag their question with Psychology. Hence, why remove it?
Related : Why is this stack exchange called 'Cognitive Sciences'? and What should we change the name of our site to, if anything?
